# Use value in cell as range in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the value in cell as a dynamic way to change the range in my macro, more specifically when changing the colour of a cell.

Lets says CELL A1 hosts the desirable range data. The macro will always look at this cell. The text in A1 = 'B4' therefore I want this to be the selected cell to have a colour fill. This will be repeated quite a few times and the data will change, this is why i need it to be a dynamic macro not conditional formatting.

Below is the standard colour macro and is far as i can get, VBA noob sorry.

```
Sub Colour2()
'
' Colour2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 16731903
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks for your understanding and help.
M

Comment: What triggers the macro?

Comment: Its a manual trigger AKA run - which im happy with

Comment: So you want that if the selected cell is equal to A1 then change the selected cell's color?

Comment: It seems like this could be done with conditional formatting

Comment: Probably slight missword on my behalf, not related at all to any form of IF. The data in A1 will change, it could be B4 it could be E42 or anything. I just want the macro to dynamically change the range which is in A1.

Once solved i will replicated this over 400 times and too complex for conditional formatting.

So for clarity, what ever the data is in cell A1, i want this to be the range within the macro. Thanks again

Comment: I think you are saying you want to put an address or range in cell A1 and have the macro fill in those cells.  I am not 100% certain.

Comment: Yea correct. If cell A1 has the text ‘E5’, I want to run the macro and cell E5 is filled in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Highlight Range Supplied in a Cell

- This is an automated solution. You run nothing. Just copy the codes in the appropriate modules.
- As you change the range address in cell `A1`, the color is applied to the cells of the supplied range address and the range is selected.

**Sheet object module e.g. `Sheet1` (the name not in parentheses in the `VBE Project Explorer`)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const mAddress As String = "A1"
    Const ColorValue As Long = 16731903
    
    Dim mCell As Range: Set mCell = Range(mAddress)
    If Not Intersect(mCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range(mCell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ' Removes the colors from all cells before applying the color.
            applyColor rg, ColorValue, True
            ' Applies the color without removing the previously applied colors.
            'applyColor rg, ColorValue
            rg.Select
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. Module1 (optionally in the same sheet object module)**

```
Sub applyColor( _
        ByVal rg As Range, _
        ByVal ColorValue As Long, _
        Optional ByVal resetBeforeApply As Boolean = False)
    If resetBeforeApply Then
        rg.Worksheet.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    End If
    With rg.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = ColorValue
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

- The standard module is preferred because it could then easily be used for other worksheets.

Comment: Thanks very much for this response. I think due to my lack of VBA knowledge I'm struggling to get this to work. It sounds like it is the solution to my problem which is great but I've copied the code and made modules but nothing is happening. Thanks again

Comment: Also, Ive made a macro that i want this to link onto so im happy with being a seperate macro rather than happening automatically

Comment: Trying all day and no luck, any other suggestions

Comment: Sorry, when I'm at work, I'm kind of read-only. Could you explain accurately what you are expecting? Use plain words. Maybe before try to enable this to work. You have to go to VBE (CTRL+F11). Then you have to open the `Project Explorer`. Then you will see a 1. list of worksheets, 2. `ThisWorkbook` and 3. perhaps `Module1`. The complete code can be copied in one of the worksheets modules. If you want this to happen in `Sheet1`, then double-click `Sheet1` and in the newly opened window paste the code. Now exit `VBE` and write `A2:A5` in cell `A1` and cells `A2:A5` should be selected and pink.

Comment: After playing around with it for a while, you will be able to explain what is wrong and I'll try to fix it. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpwyDcCVKMuwFXO_gpOaKjR7s-CyYLFi/view?usp=sharing) is a copy of my file. Download it and try it.

Comment: Sweet i have it working with the file working.

I've tried to edit it so it doesn't remove the colours as I'm happy for the old colours to stay.

Comment: Great i fixed it at the same time, thanks so much for help. finally is there a way to not get it to remove previous colours?

Comment: Easy as pie: just replace `Const ColorValue As Long = 16731903` with `Dim ColorValue As Long: ColorValue = Range("E1").Value` or if you meant to use the color of cell `E1`, do `ColorValue = Range("E1").Interior.Color` I didn't notice you mentioning `E1` anywhere before. To not remove previous colors just remove the `, True` in `applyColor rg, ColorValue, True`: it should be `applyColor rg, ColorValue` (short for `applyColor rg, ColorValue, False` (`False` is default)).

Comment: you are the man! 1 final thing, is there a way I can repeat this, I need this done 30 times haha, ive tried copying and pasting the code and just changing the reference but it doesnt work. Cant thank you enough

Comment: What will change each time?

Comment: So we have it set up atm that A1 colours in a cell. But I want this to work on multiple at the same time. So let’s say A1, B1, C1, D1 etc all has a range in that I want the cell to be filled in

Comment: Ive tried copying the code and pasting at the bottom whilst changing mAddress but it doesnt work unfortunately